# Structure Map Error Code 202

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, structuremap

I am fairly used to using Structure Map IoC with MVC, but have recently had to adapt it to legacy web forms.

I have done this by providing a **IoCContainer** class that has a **Configure()** method on it such as the following that handles the registry.

```
    public static void Configure()
    {
        var log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (Global1));

        log.Debug("Initializing Container");
        /*Initialize IoC Container*/
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                                     {
            x.For<ITokenService>().Use<TokenService>();
            x.For<ILocalizationService>().Use<LocalizationService>();

            log.Debug("Initializing Object Factory");
            /*Setup Property Injection*/
            x.SetAllProperties(p =>
                                   {
                                       p.OfType<ITokenService>();
                                       p.OfType<ILocalizationService>();
                                   });
        });

    }
```

I have provided a base control that contains the **BuildUp()** method BasePage.cs, such as the following.

```
    public BasePage()
    {
        var log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (Global1));
        log.Debug("Base Page Build Up");
        /*Inject Dependencies*/
        ObjectFactory.BuildUp(this);
    }
```

In one of my classes I am using autowiring to inject the LocalizationService into an ILocalization Property.

Everything works perfectly fine on my local machine, but for some reason, when I deploy this code to our staging server, it is giving me the following StructureMap Exception:

**StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily SuperShuttle.Web.Applications.Reservations.Interfaces.Services.ILocalizationService, SuperShuttle.Web.Applications.Reservations, Version=3.6.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null**

Not quite sure why it would change when I deploy my application, especially since I am just copying and pasting the files.

**Edit** I am calling **IoCContainer.Configure()** in **Application_Start()** of Global.asax such as the following:

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        log.Debug("In Application Start - Pre BuildUp");
        /*Configure Ioc Container*/
        IocConfigurator.Configure();
    }
```

Comment: Regarding why you are getting different behaviour when you deploy locally, could it be that when working locally you are launching it from Visual Studio and deploying it on the built-in ASP.NET Development Server (default), while your staging server is IIS?